# Set a single message for Required Textbox In mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC4 .I want to set many  textboxs as a **Required**  like this :

```
         public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "test")]
        [StringLength(10,ErrorMessage = "کد ملی باید ده رقمی باشد",MinimumLength = 10)]
```

So i have to write a error message for each Textbox.So it is time consuming.How can i set a single message for all required Textboxes in MVC4 ?

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a **Custom** Required Attribute by `Overriding` the existing **Required** Attribute as follows:

```
public class RequiredAttribute : System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute
{
    private string _propertyName;

    public RequiredAttribute([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        _propertyName = propertyName;
    }

    public string PropertyName
    {
        get { return _propertyName; }
    }

    private string GetErrorMessage()
    {
      //Provide your Error Message Here..           
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        //note that the display name for the field is passed to the 'name' argument
        return string.Format(GetErrorMessage(), name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have 8 class in my DomainModel .so i how can use this Overriding  for other classes?

Comment: @EA ..do you need the same error message for all the fields ? or is it differernt ?

Comment: @ EA ..Then you can use the overridden Required tag for all the fields

Answer (score 1):

I would just use the signature where you can pull your error messages from a resource file.  That way you set the error message in one place and just have your required attributes look something like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MyResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorMessageForRequired")]
```

Here's an [article](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/12/07/localizing-aspnetmvc-validation.aspx/) about this from Phil Haack.

Comment: Can u give me an example of using Resource!?

Comment: I provided you the link to an article discussing how to create the resource file and then how to use the resource file in your model.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't provide  ErrorMessage  for anytextbox and user validationsummary